# unresolved dependencies with rollup

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

I have the following rollup config:

```
import cjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import json from "rollup-plugin-json";

export default {
  input: "lib/state-info.js",
  output: {
    file: "rolled.js",
    format: "cjs"
  },
  external: ["aws-sdk"],
  plugins: [
    json(),
    cjs({
      include: "node_modules/**",
      exclude: ["node_modules/aws-sdk/**"]
    }),
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: false,
      preferBuiltins: false,
      extensions: [".js", ".json"]
    })
  ]
};
```

And I'm rolling up successfully but warned that there are a lot of *unresolved dependencies*. The following functions are subset of those missing:

> process (imported by lib/vote-smart/get-state-info.js, node_modules/abstracted-admin/lib/db.js, commonjs-external:process)
>   http (imported by node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js, node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js, commonjs-external:http, node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js, node_modules/request/request.js, node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/lib/signer.js, node_modules/forever-agent/index.js, node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js, node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js)
>
> https (imported by node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js, node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js, commonjs-external:https, node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/token-generator.js, node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js, node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js, node_modules/request/request.js, node_modules/forever-agent/index.js, node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js, node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js)
>
> dgram (imported by node_modules/request/node_modules/sntp/lib/index.js, commonjs-external:dgram)
>
> tls (imported by node_modules/forever-agent/index.js, commonjs-external:tls, node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js)
>   constants (imported by node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js, commonjs-external:constants)
>
> memcpy (imported by node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/bytebuffer-node.js, commonjs-external:memcpy)
>
> timers (imported by node_modules/google-gax/lib/api_callable.js, commonjs-external:timers)

I'm very new to rollup, am I missing anything obvious?

---

Note, I presume functions like `process` and `fs` which are part of node itself can just be added as "external" and all should be good, right? Functions like `memcpy` or `timers` are a mystery on why they're not being detected by static analysis.

---

UPDATE: I have found that all but two of my unresolved dependencies can be addressed simply by adding the `rollup-plugin-node-builtins` plugin. The two that remain are:

- **memcpy** and **fast-crc32c**

I can install `fast-crc32c` locally to the dependencies and this problem goes away (although I'm not sure why I need to do this) but when I try to do the same for `memcpy` it fails to install.